# How to deal with very large file in request body in REST API?

Tags: rest

I have created a rest api. It supports multipart/form-data request type. My API clients used to attach content of files in their system to POST request body. It works fine. But recently there is need for very large input files. I think it will not be a good idead to attach very large file in request itself.

> How do I handle very large request payload(input file content) in my REST API?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 2):

> I think it will not be a good idead to attach very large file in request itself.

There is nothing inherently wrong with attaching very large files to a REST API request.

Some web application frameworks may not be designed for large file uploads and may have problems with handling really large files (e.g. they may try to buffer the entire request in memory, and run out of memory on files that are larger than memory), but this is implementation issue, not an API design issue.

Comment: any implementation suggestion?

Comment: you should read this  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-associated-data-to-a-restful-webservice-preferably-as-json]

Comment: And my question is any of the solution is not suitable for larger files. so any implementation suggestion?

Comment: @SurajShrestha: as already said, there is nothing inherently wrong with uploading large files to a REST API. If you have implementation-specific issue, you need to describe your implementation environment, requirements, and what problems you are currently stuck on in much more detail than what you currently have in your question. Why is none of the proposed solutions in that page suit your situation?